# How to does _.reduce work in _.every underscore js re-implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I've been confused with how _.reduce works here all day.

```js
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    var check = iterator || _.identity;
    var result = _.reduce(collection, function(accumulator, val) {
      return accumulator && !!check(val);
    }, true);
    return result;
  };
  
  console.log(_.every([true, false, 1, 2, 3, 4], _.identity)); // ===> false
```

So as i understand _.reduce it goes through the collection and for each element the iterator(accum, val), is called on each element in the array, and then return the accumulator, but I don't understand what line 4 is doing: return accumulator && !!check(val);. How come it doesn't check false, set that as the accumulator, then go to check 1 and set that as the accumulator, then move on to the rest of the array until it gets to 4 which would means the last accumulator is true? Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: If the accumulator is `true`, then a call to `check()` is made, and that's the return value from the `.reduce()` callback. If the accumulator is `false`, then `check()` is not called, and `false` is returned.

Comment: The reduce function is essentially evaluating `(((((true && !!true) && !!false) && !!1) && !!2) && !!3) && !!4`, where the first `true` is the initial value that `accumulator` has, set in line 5.

Answer (score 1):

`.every` is basically a compound `&&`. The result should only be `true` if every single element also results in `true`.

So in this line of code...

```
return accumulator && !!check(val);
```

...`accumulator` is the value so far.

If accumulator is `true`, then everything's fine so far. It will call `check` on the current element of the array, convert the result to a boolean, and return that. The returned value becomes the `accumulator` on the next step.

If accumulator is `false`, it's because something earlier in the array returned `false`. That means we've already failed, and there's no need to keep checking the rest of the array. Even if something later in the array returns `true` it won't matter.  Thus this expression will return `false`, and not even bother calling `check`.